# How to Extract the Noun Phrases using Open NLP

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I am new to Open NLP and need some help in extracting noun phrases using it. I have generated a tree structure which contains the pos tags with the text. But from the tree structure I am not able to extract the noun phrases. Here is the code I am using:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("en-parser-chunking.bin");
ParserModel model = new ParserModel(is);
Parser parser = ParserFactory.create(model);
Parse topParses[] = ParserTool.parseLine(line, parser, 1);
    for (Parse p : topParses){
             p.show();}
```

Here `p.show()` prints the tree structure and it does not return anything. How can I use `p.show()` to extract the noun phrases or is there any other way to get them from  the tree structure?

Please help me on this.

Thanks in Advance

Gouse.